# Broadcast receiver invoking on every reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a broadcast Receiver with which should wake the application up on every reboot,

```
   receiver android:name=".Receiver.NewLocationReceiver" 
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="YouWillNeverKillMe" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Still the BOOT_COMPLETE filter if failing to do its job, Unable to tackle a particular scenario. Is there anything I need to add so that I can completely avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Popular pitfalls:

1. BOOT_COMPLETED is delivered to all relevant (registered) broadcast receivers only upon unlocking the device.
2. It is delivered in some order, so you may be last in that list and will take some time.
3. Make sure you have the presmission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`